# Downloading files with camel-http

Tags: apache-camel

Have an `ArrayList` of URL's coming into a route. I am using `Splitter EIP` to split the ArrayList into into individual strings each of which is a URL. I want to download files associated with those URLs and wrap them into a `File` object. Here is what I have tried so far :

```
  from("direct:downloadFiles")
       .split(body())
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
          .to("http4://${body}")
           .process (new TestProcessor())
```

Cannot seem to find a good example anywhere on how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Camel this is very simple. Just use this instead of your last two lines of the route.

```
.toD("http4://${body}")
.to("file://target");
```

Notice these issues:

- You have to use `.toD()` instead of `.to()` since your endpoint is not static but a dynamic expression
- Since the `.toD()` HTTP call puts the downloaded document into the message body you can simply write the body to a file by using `.to("file://[folder])`
- If you want to set a specific filename you can set it through the message header `CamelFileName` or an endpoint option `filename`